# An empty sqlite database takes 74 Mb?

Tags: sqlite

[image]

[image]

Why?

Comment: Is yours a freshly created one?

Comment: Please add a description about the database. Is it a new one? or did you delete all the tables? Were there data before?

Answer (score 8):

Because it needs to be [shrunk](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

> Unless SQLite is running in
>   "auto_vacuum=FULL" mode, when a large
>   amount of data is deleted from the
>   database file it leaves behind empty
>   space, or "free" database pages. This
>   means the database file might be
>   larger than strictly necessary.
>   Running VACUUM to rebuild the database
>   reclaims this space and reduces the
>   size of the database file.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting tables from Database does not decrease its size in Sqlite. Its size will remain same as the maximum size attained yet

Comment: Why  is it designed this way?

Comment: For performance reasons. Truncated a file may be an expensive operation for some file systems. You can use the vacuum command if you really want to compact the database file.